# Only join rows that meet certain criteria (left join of data that is left joined)

Tags: sql, join, doctrine-orm, left-join

I have users that have FacebookPage and Application entities associated to them. FacebookPage entities also have Application entities associated with them.

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->addSelect('p', 'a')
        ->leftJoin('u.facebook_pages', 'p')
        ->leftJoin('p.applications', 'a')
        ->leftJoin('a.editors', 'e', 'WITH', 'e = :user')
        ->where('u = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->orderBy('p.name', $order)
        ;

    $u = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();

    return $u->getFacebookPages();
```

I want to return all of the user's Facebook pages and then show a count of applications associated with that page. I only want to count the applications where the user is an editor.

When run my current query, the pages have a count with all the page's applications (so the count includes applications where the user is not an editor).

If I change the `a.editors` `leftJoin` to a `join`, I get the correct counts for the pages, but it only lists pages that actually have any applications.

How can I show all the pages and only join the applications where the user is an editor?

Comment: I think it might help if I could somehow leftJoin the applications with `:user IN (a.editors)`

Comment: I also tried creating a query builder on the Facebook Page entity and left joining the applications where the editors include the user, but this only shows me the pages where the user is an editor and not all of the user's pages.

Comment: just to give you a direction: you need to use group by "pages" and then count aplications and make a if-else to set counter to 0 if non aplication found.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a new query to get app ids for the applications where user is an editor.

```
    $user_apps = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Application')->getUserApps($user);
    $app_ids = array();
    foreach($user_apps as $app) {
        $app_ids[] = $app->getId();
    }

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->addSelect('p', 'a')
        ->leftJoin('u.facebook_pages', 'p');

    if(count($app_ids)) {
        // join with IN statement to include only apps where user is an editor
        $qb->leftJoin('p.applications', 'a', 'WITH', sprintf('a.id IN (%s)', implode(',', $app_ids)));
    } else {
        // join empty anyway to avoid db calls when iterating over pages
        $qb->leftJoin('p.applications', 'a');
    }

    $qb
        ->where('u = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->orderBy('p.name', $order)
        ;

    try {
        $u = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    }

    return $u->getFacebookPages();
```

This now returns all the user's Facebook pages and only join applications where user is an editor. I am probably going to change this to a DQL query so I can move the ids in `IN` to a subquery.